# How to delete a specific shape from a HTML canvas by double clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I would like to delete a triangle that I just created by double clicking on the shape.

This is the code I am using to draw shapes:

```
var canvas,
    context,
    dragging = true,
    dragStartLocation,
    snapshot;


function getCanvasCoordinates(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    return {x: x, y: y};
}

function takeSnapshot() {
    snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function restoreSnapshot() {
    context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
}
function drawPolygon(position, sides, angle) {
    var coordinates = [],
        radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2)),
        index = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < sides; index++) {
        coordinates.push({x: dragStartLocation.x + radius * Math.cos(angle), y: dragStartLocation.y - radius * Math.sin(angle)});
        angle += (2 * Math.PI) / sides;
    }

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
    for (index = 1; index < sides; index++) {
        context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
    }

    context.closePath();
}

function draw(position) {
     drawPolygon(position, 3, 90 * (Math.PI / 180));
        context.fillStyle =getRandomColor();
        context.fill();
       // context.stroke();
}

function dragStart(event) {
    dragging = true;
    dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    takeSnapshot();
}

function drag(event) {
    var position;
    if (dragging === true) {
        restoreSnapshot();
        position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
        draw(position, "polygon");
    }
}

function dragStop(event) {
    dragging = false;
    restoreSnapshot();
    var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    draw(position, "polygon");
}

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
function clearCanvas()
{
    clickX = new Array();
    clickY = new Array();
    clickDrag = new Array();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas
}
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   // context.strokeStyle = 'black';
     // context.fillStyle = 'red';
  //  context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.lineCap = 'round';


    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);
}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);



    var canvas,
        context,
        dragging = true,
        dragStartLocation,
        snapshot;


    function getCanvasCoordinates(event) {
        var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left,
            y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        return {x: x, y: y};
    }

    function takeSnapshot() {
        snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    function restoreSnapshot() {
        context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
    }
    function drawPolygon(position, sides, angle) {
        var coordinates = [],
            radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2)),
            index = 0;

        for (index = 0; index < sides; index++) {
            coordinates.push({x: dragStartLocation.x + radius * Math.cos(angle), y: dragStartLocation.y - radius * Math.sin(angle)});
            angle += (2 * Math.PI) / sides;
        }

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
        for (index = 1; index < sides; index++) {
            context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
        }

        context.closePath();
    }

    function draw(position) {
         drawPolygon(position, 3, 90 * (Math.PI / 180));
            context.fillStyle =getRandomColor();
            context.fill();
           // context.stroke();
    }

    function dragStart(event) {
        dragging = true;
        dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
        takeSnapshot();
    }

    function drag(event) {
        var position;
        if (dragging === true) {
            restoreSnapshot();
            position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
            draw(position, "polygon");
        }
    }

    function dragStop(event) {
        dragging = false;
        restoreSnapshot();
        var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
        draw(position, "polygon");
    }

    function getRandomColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      return color;
    }
    function clearCanvas()
    {
        clickX = new Array();
        clickY = new Array();
        clickDrag = new Array();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas
    }
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       // context.strokeStyle = 'black';
         // context.fillStyle = 'red';
      //  context.lineWidth = 4;
        context.lineCap = 'round';


        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
    *{
        border:0;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    h2{
         position: absolute;
        top:10%;
        left:43%;
    }

    canvas{
        position: relative;
        top: 100px;
        left:400px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
    button{
        position:absolute;
        top: 95%;
        left: 65%;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }

    #controls{
        position: absolute;
        top:100px;
        left:5px;
        padding:20px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        background-color: lightskyblue;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px lightskyblue;
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>html5canvas</title>
        <link href="triangle.css" rel="stylesheet">
       

        <script src="triangle.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>simple painting app</h2>
     <div class="wrapper">
     <button onClick="clearCanvas()" class="button">CLEAR</button>
    </div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is [Double Click Func](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) in jquery, you can find the api code and use it as pure js code.

Comment: "dblclick" is a native event in JavaScript. No need to use jQuery or its source here!? :?

Comment: @Teemoh Its just about source